# Why Alertmanager failed to send alerts to slack

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have created alerts, that fires and can be seen in Alertmanager. So previously I was able to get notifications to the Slack channel. I don't know what caused the issue, now unable to get notifications. I have gone through this [Prometheus alert manager doesnt send alert k8s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59460374/prometheus-alert-manager-doesnt-send-alert-k8s), but didn't find a way. Any help would be appreciated.

`alertmanager.yaml`

```yaml
global:
  slack_api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/some-dummy'
route:
  group_by: [Alertname]
  # Send all notifications to me.
  receiver: 'slack notifications'
receivers:
  - name: 'slack notifications'
    slack_configs:
      - channel: '#alerts'
        text: "{{ .Annotations.summary }}\n{{ .Annotations.description }}\n{{ end }}"
```

Prometheus UI
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the logs of the alertmanager?

Comment: log says issue with {{ .Annotations.summary }} and {{ .Annotations.description}}. failed to parse. @JensBaitinger

Comment: Totally not related, but might be helpful. YAML supports multiline strings: https://yaml-multiline.info/. You won't need to put everything in a single line and use `\n` as new-line character.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `{{ end }}`, there mighte have been a {{ range .Alerts }} in the begining, but withot that, the `{{ end }}` does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
receivers:
  - name: 'default-receiver'
    slack_configs:
    - channel: 'alerts'
    - title: "{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .Annotations.summary }}\n{{ end }}"
    - text: "{{ range .Alerts }}{{ .Annotations.description }}\n{{ end }}"
```